# Groups & organizations in FATE Core

Tags: fate-core, fantasy

I'm trying to find the best way to model groups and organizations in FATE Core for a city of intrigue and revolution in a fantasy world. So the group would be a character. So far I've adapted this from the Hell's Rebels Adventure Path (from Pathfinder), but I'm trying to expand it to cover more options

The aspects would be around the group's Focus (or goals), it's Scale (EG Local, City-wide, Regional, National, Global, Planetary) and any other aspects that would be considers important to it.

The groups skills would be Influence, Spy-network (or Military Intelligence), Military (or thugs), Criminal elements, and Suppliers (or financiers).
Does the Aspects, Skills and stress tracks express possible groups well? Are these edge cases or unusual groups that would not be cover or things I have missed?

The stress tracks would cover Organizational Coherency, and Wealth.
Consequences for Organizational Coherency can include Low morale, Infiltrated, Riddled with spies, Winded, or Crestfallen.
For Wealth stress it can be broke, skint, out of cash, In debt to , 
However, I have a problem in writing good consequences for the stress tracks?

Comment: I've voted to close this as it's not the kind of question we handle well. "Any suggestions?" and "any ideas?" are idea-generation requests and we don't handle those - they're discussion-y questions where every answer is equally valid. "Does this cover possible groups well?" is slightly more legit but a very weird question: yes? some? maybe? and not others maybe? If you're trying to achieve a certain goal you might be better off asking if this achieves it effectively. You may want to ask [meta.rpg.se] where to go from here with this question.

Comment: It's rewritten to reflect that I'm looking for validation of the idea and to check for gaps in my thinking.

Comment: I think you would be best asking about this stuff [on a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/1204), such as [the Fate RPG reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FATErpg/). You're looking for a discussion, where our site's fine-tuned for problems that can have a single best solution.

Answer (score 0):

IME, Scale is usually handled by a shift in success qualifiers. Regional organizations competing vs Local organizations are considered 2 shifts higher on the same roll. It would pretty +Good (+3)for a smaller organization to accomplish what a larger one would think of as a pretty +Average (+1) day.

Aspects seem, to me, to be descriptions of the organization. "A bloodthirsty Eastern European Mafia." A goal doesn't give you much to work with as an aspect, so far as I can see. "Seeking to rule the world" might apply to every roll, doesn't tell you much. "...through military conquest" is better. "A secret fraternity of PMC CEOS and Military Generals who worship fallen gods through bloody conquest" would be best, IMHO.

Regarding the skills, I think they're fine - but isn't just about any skill an organization has also a stress track? Wealth can be used to do things, but it is also spent and lost. Thugs go thugging, but they also get injured.

Oh, and do you mean "Morale?"

Comment: I'm planning on using the scale the way you suggest, but I haven't worked out the shifts. And thanks for the ideas around the aspects.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Moral. It could reflect the Moral of the group, but I can not think of appropriate consequences. However, if the stress track is Organisational Coherency, then the Moral could be consequences.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean *morale*, regarding whether or not the group is in good spirits and feeling motivated?